# Excluding repeated maxima in R

Tags: r

I am trying to identify maxima/minima in a data set, and I'm using the following code:

```
find_peaks <- function (x, m = 3){
    shape <- diff(sign(diff(x, na.pad = FALSE)))
    pks <- sapply(which(shape < 0), FUN = function(i){
       z <- i - m + 1
       z <- ifelse(z > 0, z, 1)
       w <- i + m + 1
       w <- ifelse(w < length(x), w, length(x))
       if(all(x[c(z : i, (i + 2) : w)] <= x[i + 1])) return(i) else
return(numeric(0))
    })
     pks <- unlist(pks)
     pks
}
```

from stas g's comment [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22974/how-to-find-local-peaks-valleys-in-a-series-of-data). However, in my data set there are some repeated maxima, so when I run the code, it returns

```
find_peaks(data$Value)
[1]   9  19  30  42  43  56  69  80  92 107 118 130 143 154 164 176 188 199 211 222 234 245
```

where data points 42 and 43 have the same value.

In a case like this I would want it to keep the first value and reject the second value. I'm pretty new to R (and coding in general) and I haven't been able to figure out a good way to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe this question is more suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: How about your share some sample data so that we can fun the function too? Simulated data (with a set seed) or data shared using `dput()` is preferred.

Comment: Careful with this. Consider what happens when you let `x <- sin(seq(-10,10,.01))` and calculate the peaks `p <- find_peaks(x)`. You get maxima at each value k*pi/2 for k = ...-1,0,1,2,.... Yet `length(unique(x[p]))` is `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I modify `find_peaks` to use `base` `diff` (which does not have an `na.pad` argument).  The only modification is to add 1 to the index at the end. (Check the output and modify accordingly if you have an `xts` object.)

```
find_peaks <- function (x, m = 3){
    shape <- diff(sign(diff(x)))
    pks <- sapply(which(shape < 0), FUN = function(i){
       z <- i - m + 1
       z <- ifelse(z > 0, z, 1)
       w <- i + m + 1
       w <- ifelse(w < length(x), w, length(x))
       if(all(x[c(z : i, (i + 2) : w)] <= x[i + 1])) return(i) else
return(numeric(0))
    })
     pks <- unlist(pks)
     pks + 1
}
```

Make some sample data (which, as noted in the comments, is good practice to include in your original question):

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- sample(1:10, 100, replace=TRUE)
pks <- find_peaks(dat)
plot(seq_along(dat), dat, type="l")
points(pks, dat[pks], pch=16, col="red")
```

[image]

The question is how to remove consecutive maxima.  One way is to identify index numbers that are consecutive, and remove them:

```
new_pks <- pks[c(TRUE, diff(pks)!=1)]
plot(seq_along(dat), dat, type="l")
points(pks, dat[pks], pch=16, col="red")
points(new_pks, dat[new_pks], pch=16, col="blue")
```

Only the blue dots are retained.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if the question was answered satisfactorily.